# postgresql - trouble to order a list obtained by string_agg

Tags: order-by, postgresql-9.6, natural-sort

I obtained a list of numbers (and text) by a string_agg.

For instance, that :

```
"09,12,20,200,217,400,500,90,91,92,Exp3"
```

This is the string_agg:

```
string_agg(DISTINCT t_ligne.ligne_code::text, ','::text ORDER BY (t_ligne.ligne_code::text)) AS lignes
```

My trouble with the ordering: I need an alphanumeric order like:

```
"09,12,20,90,91,92,200,217,400,500,Exp3"
```

If I try a CAST, it refuses to accept text "numbers" like "Exp3".

So I didn't find any way to order it like values with text objects at the end.

EDIT
I don't know how to use WITH in my query without cutting my results!
In fact, this is the total query:

```
SELECT l_arret_ligne.idap,
       t_arret.nom_arret AS nom,
       string_agg(DISTINCT t_ligne.ligne_code::text, ','::text ORDER BY (t_ligne.ligne_code::text)) AS lignes
FROM l_arret_ligne,
     t_ligne,
     t_arret
WHERE l_arret_ligne.id_ligne::text = t_ligne.id_ligne::text 
  AND l_arret_ligne.idap::text = t_arret.idap::text 
  AND t_ligne.ligne_type::text <> 'Scolaire'::text
GROUP BY l_arret_ligne.idap, t_arret.nom_arret
```

As my string_agg is inside a global query, I don't understand how it would be possible to cut it with WITH and globalize it at the end.

Maybe do I understand bad...

Thanks again!

EDIT 2:
Hello again!
I found one very good solution to order my results:

```
SELECT string_agg("rla"."t_ligne_19032019"."ligne_code", ',' ORDER BY case when (UPPER(ligne_code)=LOWER(ligne_code))=true then substring(concat('000000000000000',ligne_code),length(ligne_code)+1,15) else ligne_code end) AS lignes
FROM "rla"."t_ligne_19032019"
```

It works very well. BUT always the same trouble with DISTINCT!
If I add DISTINCT in the string_agg, same message:

> ERROR:  in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must
>   appear in argument list

Any solution? Any advice?

Thanks again!

Cyril

Comment: *I need an alphanumeric order like* It is NOT A-order. Does you need something like "first numbers ordered by value, then A-ordered non-numbers" ? Build proper expression using CASE statement.

Comment: For example, simply add zero-padding to some fixed char length, if the value is numeric one...

Comment: Thanks. CASE is a trouble, because I can not use ORDER BY CASE with DISTINCT, pgsql does not accept.

Comment: *I can not use ORDER BY CASE with DISTINCT* Move the query to WITH, and order its result in outer query.

Comment: Well… I guess this should help me… But I do not see how to do such a thing… Can you be more precise? Sorry but I am not an expert...

Comment: `case when trim(str) similar to '[0-9]+' then right(repeat('0',99)||trim(str),100) else str end` - assuming 100 is `MAX(LENGTH(str))`

Comment: That sounds very nice! But ORDER BY CASE is not accepted by pgsql when using a DISTINCT...

Comment: If so move its calculation to WITH section.

Comment: Thanks. You told me that once, but I am really not sure how to do that. Is it a WITH before SELECT?

Comment: *Is it a WITH before SELECT?* Of course.

Comment: Why are you converting all column values to text for the comparison in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

The `order by` in a `string_agg()` can absolutely use a CASE expression:

```
with data (ligne_code) as (
  values 
  ('a value'), ('09'), ('12'), ('20'), ('007'), 
  ('200'), ('92'), ('11'), ('Foo'), ('Exp3')
) 
select string_agg(ligne_code, ',' order by case when ligne_code ~'^[0-9]+$' then ligne_code::int end, ligne_code)
from data;
```

returns:

```
007,09,11,12,20,92,200,a value,Exp3,Foo
```

The expression `when ligne_code ~'^[0-9]+$'` checks if `ligne_code` consists of numbers. If that is the case it's converted to an integer which is the first sort criteria. All non-numbers come after that and are sorted in a alphabetic way.